Fetching numerical content from string in informatica
I have requirement
I have one input port contains following string value" rad of experience (kms) : 0-50 "
I want to fetch only max value from this i.e.,50  please help me how to fetch max numerical values?
I tried reg_extract and substr but output is not as expeected

Hi - is the value you want always preceded by a “-“ and is this always the only occurrence of a “-“ in your string? If not, what are the rules to identify where the required number appears in the string?

That's the only occurence

Extracting the characters after the “-“ to end of the string is pretty straightforward:

Find the position of the “-“ using INSTR
Extract the numeric value using SUBSTR, starting at the value + 1 found in point 1 and going to end of the string
Potentially TRIM the result and convert it to a number, if necessary

